# Python/Pandas finding missing items amongst similarly grouped data, nested iteration not efficient

Tags: python, pandas

I will start by saying I am VERY new to python/pandas. I have a dataframe with about 1.5 million rows of data and growing, below is an abstraction of the data. I am trying to find hosts in the same release and group, where a host is missing a path that other hosts have in common. My approach was to iterate through the data, it is not very efficient. Appreciate any feedback on different approach, or increasing performance on my current approach. Thank You

## Result

| release | group | host | missing_path | ReferenceHosts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | one | abc | c:\one\three | def:ghi |

## Data

| release | group | host | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | one | abc | c:\one\two |
| A | one | def | c:\one\two |
| A | one | def | c:\one\three |
| A | one | ghi | c:\one\two |
| A | one | ghi | c:\one\three |
| A | two... lots of groups | ... | ... |
| B... lots of releases | ... | ... | ... |

```js
    #get unique list of releases
    list_releases = df['Release'].dropna().unique().tolist()

    #get unique list groups
    list_groups = df['Group'].dropna().unique().tolist()


    #build dictionary { group:[hosts], }
    lists_hosts = hosts_by_group(list_groups, df)

    #detect missing files
    audit_missing = find_missing_files(list_releases, lists_hosts, df)
```

```js
overview = {"Release": [], "Group": [], "SubjectHost": [], "FileMissing": [], "ReferenceHosts": [], "Ref1Domain": [], "Ref2Domain": [], "SubjDomain": [], "Extension": []}

def generate_overview(grp, hst, ref, hi, ref1_domain, ref2_domain, subj_domain, df,release,hosts, checking_host, idx2):

    df1 = df[(df.Hostname == hosts[idx2]) & (df.Release == release)]
    df2 = df[(df.Hostname == hosts[hi]) & (df.Release == release)]
    merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on=["Path"]).dropna()
    merge2 = pd.merge(checking_host, merge, how="inner", on=["Path"]).dropna()

    files_not_found = merge[~merge["Path"].isin(merge2["Path"])].dropna()
    iter = files_not_found['Path'].tolist()
    count = files_not_found['Path'].count()
        
    if files_not_found.count().sum() > 0:
        
        for file in iter:
            ext = files_not_found.loc[files_not_found['Path'] == file, 'Extension_x'].item()            
            overview["Release"].append(release)
            overview["Group"].append(grp)
            overview["SubjectHost"].append(hst)
            overview["FileMissing"].append(file)
            overview["ReferenceHosts"].append(ref) 
            overview["Ref1Domain"].append(ref1_domain) 
            overview["Ref2Domain"].append(ref2_domain) 
            overview["SubjDomain"].append(subj_domain) 
            overview["Extension"].append(ext)
```

```js
 def missing_file_process(hosts,df, group, release):
        for idx1, host in enumerate(hosts):
        
            checking_host = df[(df.Hostname == host)]
            subj_domain = (checking_host.Domain.unique())[0]

            for idx2, host2 in enumerate(hosts):
                num_hosts = len(hosts)             
                ref = ''
                hosts_index = 0
                ref1_domain = ''
                ref2_domain = ''

                if num_hosts - idx2 < 2:
                    ref = hosts[idx2] + ":" + hosts[0]
                    hosts_index = 0
                    ref1_domain = (df[(df.Hostname == hosts[idx2])].Domain.unique())[0]
                    ref2_domain = (df[(df.Hostname == hosts[0])].Domain.unique())[0]
                if num_hosts - idx2 > 1:
                    ref = hosts[idx2] + ":" + hosts[idx2+1]
                    hosts_index = idx2+1
                    ref1_domain = (df[(df.Hostname == hosts[idx2])].Domain.unique())[0]
                    ref2_domain = (df[(df.Hostname == hosts[idx2+1])].Domain.unique())[0]
                
                generate_overview( group, host, ref, hosts_index, ref1_domain, ref2_domain, subj_domain, df, release,hosts, checking_host, idx2)
```

```js
 def find_missing_files(releases, lists_hosts, df):
        
        for release in releases:

            for idx, (group, hosts) in enumerate(lists_hosts.items()):
                 if len(hosts) > 2:
                    missing_file_process(hosts,df, group, release)

        return pd.DataFrame(data=overview)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
# Find all unique paths in a Release Group
tmp1 = df.groupby(['release', 'group'])['path'].apply(set).to_frame('path1').reset_index()

# Find all unique paths per Host in a Release Group
tmp2 = df.groupby(['release', 'group', 'host'])['path'].apply(set).to_frame('path2').reset_index()

# Line them up and find the missing paths in the second set
tmp3 = pd.merge(tmp1, tmp2, how='right', on=['release', 'group'])
tmp3['missing'] = tmp3['path1'] - tmp3['path2']

# Filter for those hosts where some paths are missing
result = tmp3[tmp3['missing'] != set({})]
```

Output:

```
release group                      path1 host        path2        missing
      A   one {c:\one\three, c:\one\two}  abc {c:\one\two} {c:\one\three}
```

You can rearrange the columns to taste

Comment: Excellent thank you for your response, if you see in my code I am performing an inner join on path with two hosts within a group to obtain a set of paths, this eliminates all the items unique to a machine, things like log files etc... This approach is very fast! Just need to figure out how to eliminate the extra paths.

Comment: An inner join defeats the purpose of finding anything missing between the two sets though. By definition, “inner” mean present on both sides

Comment: My current code works and has identified missing core application files on our network, but takes 5 minutes to run, ran your code in seconds I am thinking you got me 90% of the way there, just need to figure out how to get rid of noise, probably just a simple filter on path, removing items with "log" ".log" etc...

Comment: I applied a filter and matches output of my code! Thank You!